# Angular 5 for binding and filtering data to dropdown from JSON API

Tags: arrays, json, filter, angular5, bind

I am a beginner in angular 5. Right now i am working on small application in which i have to fetch JSON data from API to my dropdown lists. There are 3 dropdown menus i,e A, B and C.  and i am creating 3 arrays to have values in that 3 arrays for dropdowns. I am stuck in one problem , how do i get only unique entries in dropdown A?? as there are duplicate values also. My expected output is : when i select something from dropdown A . according to that option, its value needs to show up in dropdown B. In Dropdown C, i want to filter rest of my data through its value, so that when i select particular value from Dropdown C, respective to that values from all the 3 dropdowns needs to shown up in a table.My Sample  arrays are like this: a = [{a: "hello",a:"hy", a:"hello"}], b = [{b: "for hello", b:"for hy"}], c = [{c1:"R"}, {c2:"A"}, {c3: "I"}]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide more details in order for us to be of use. Can you include e.g. the component code?

Comment: what in the magnolia? you do realize that `a` just renames the same property 3 times? And `b` does the exact same thing?

Comment: Example data: {"a": "CI/CD",
    "b":"CI/CD Pipeline Management",
    "Dev": "R",
    "Agile": "C",
    "Scr": "",
    "SD": "I",
    "Tech":"",
    "Technicl":"A",
    "Archt":"",
    "Automation":"R"}    There is like more then 100 objects like this in my json file.  i want value of a in one dropdown , value of b in on dropdown and rest of all the values in last dropdown. only unique values.